Confusion regarding driving a MOSFET through optoisolator
I am currently developing a circuit board for a control chassis, that will control various light outputs depending on what inputs are active, no fast switching is required. I have the input side figured out and the MCU used is an Arduino Nano Every. The lights that are to be controlled are #67 BA15S bulbs, which pull .59A each, although one circuit has 4 of them in parallel(~2.7A). They are powered through a 12VDC power supply in the chassis. I plan on changing these out to LEDs(~.15A each).
I am currently designing the output side of the circuit, where I chose to use FDP16AN08A0 N-Channel MOSFETs to switch the lamps. Since this isn't a logic level MOSFET, I am using LTV-847 optocouplers that the Nano Every outputs to, which would then power the gate of the MOSFETs using an internal 10v power supply in the chassis. My confusion comes with the current transfer ratio of the optocouplers and how the resistors for the MOSFET gate should be designed in regards to it.
My current design is for the optocoupler's LED to be powered from the Arduino's output pin through a 220 ohm resistor, which would give an If of ~17mA. I then have the 10v rail connected to the collector of the optocoupler and from the emitter of the optocoupler, I have a 100k ohm gate pull-down resistor and a 470 ohm gate resistor to limit the collector current(Ic) to ~21mA. Would this work? I am confused on how the CTR of the optocoupler relates to this or if it would have an effect on the current through the collector, is it to ensure that the actual CTR of the circuit is within that range?
I also noticed in the datasheet for the optocoupler that there was different "rank marks" that had different CTRs, one would have a CTR of 50-100% while another would have a CTR of 130-260. Is there a specific one I should choose?
I provided an image of the schematic for one of the circuits below:


What's stopping you from using a BJT or logic level MOSFET? Also you'll probably want to put the LEDs in series and have a single resistor or other current limiting device for the whole string since LEDs don't split current well in parallel.

The previous logic level MOSFET I used on my older design from a few years ago was discontinued, and from my search, this one was the one that I felt most comfortable with it not needing a heat sink. The optocoupler LEDs are not going to be in parallel, they will be powered from individual Arduino outputs. For the 67 bulbs I am going to use BA15S retrofit LEDs, wouldn't rewiring them in series no longer give them 12v each?

Are the opto-couplers really necessary?  What isolation voltage rating is required between (a) the LED side of the opto and (b) the opto output side (the 12V supply to the lamps).    This voltage rating has a big impact on the practical and regulatory requirements for any real-world implementation, eg: creepage distances, acceptable devices, isolation materials, flammability, etc.  Is this product intended for a commercial marker (ie: has to meet regulatory safety standards), or is it just a DIY project?

This is to be used in a bowling alley pinsetter chassis(Made in the 1970's), this board I am designing would plug into a edge card slot that has a ground and 10v rail connected to it, the rest are inputs/outputs. The 12v line is from a separate connector on the chassis going to the lamps.

As mentioned, the rise time isn't very important, and gate current only flows during transition (gate is a capacitor, and I = C dV/dt).  This can simply be whatever current the opto is capable of, and that will give a risetime of some to tens of microseconds.  Fall time will be much slower (~ms) with the <0.1mA sink current through the 100k, which can be brought up to say half the minimum output current (minimum based on worst-case input drive and CTR) to make the edges a bit more symmetrical.
Slower turn-on may be desirable to avoid EMC issues.  Though, starting at some microseconds already, you'll need quite some lead length to run afoul of stray inductance or what have you; the opto switching is pretty safe in this regard.  Perhaps a R+C snubber on the output, and a zener type TVS, wired S to D, would suffice to prevent oscillation (while the transistor is in the linear range, during switching) and to clamp possible inductive kick or other transients.  Typical values might be 10Ω + 10nF and SMAJ24A.
Slower switching is discouraged as the transistor likely gets too hot during switching, and then pretty soon the load stays on forever as the device is likely to fail shorted.  A 100k pull-down is a bit marginal here.  But if the load is a single lamp, and the transistor is that big (TO-220), it's probably hard to run into a problem.  With more lamps in parallel (5, 10A or more?), this gets more important.
If you're changing to LEDs, I would just as well choose something small and cheap; tiny surface mounts are sufficient here.
I note you've drawn the circuit with common grounds.  If this will be the case, you can use a logic-level MOSFET directly (with a modest-value gate resistor, say 1k for comparable switching speed) and dispense with the opto.  For non-logic-level drive, a pair of transistors will do; many level-shift and gate-drive circuits can be found on searching here.  A BJT is also suitable, especially the low-Vce(sat) types like PBSS4240, etc. which have high gain so use little base current (Ic / 50 is practical) and can be driven from any MCU GPIO, even at low voltage.

The opto-coupler coupler has a minimum CTR of 50%, so if its LED current is \$I_{LED}=17mA\$, then the largest transistor collector/emitter current you can expect is:
$$ I_{C(MAX)} = 50\% \times I_{LED} = 0.5 \times 17mA \approx 8mA $$
The MOSFET won't sink/source any current via its gate (except during switching), which means that the only path for opto-coupler current is R2. Therefore, with the opto-coupler transistor fully on, you would expect this current through it:
$$ I_C = \frac{10V}{100k\Omega} = 100\mu A $$
That is tiny compared to \$I_{C(MAX)}\$. You'd have no issues at all obtaining 100μA through R2, setting the MOSFET gate near to the full 10V supply. Your circuit would work, with a caveat that I'll explain below.
A big concern when using MOSFETs to switch heavy loads, is to make them switch as fast as possible. While switched "fully on" on or "fully off" they dissipate very little power themselves, but it's the period during the transition between those states that is problematic. We generally aim to keep that switching time as short as possible.
The MOSFET gate is a small capacitance, which needs to be charged and discharged, meaning that the more current you can get into and out of that gate, the faster the MOSFET will transition between on and off states, and therefore we generally aim to maximise that current.
We already established that if you are unlucky, and your opto-coupler has the worst possible performance, you can expect no more than 8mA through its internal transistor, and that will determine the smallest value for R2. Using Ohm's law, we can find out what value of R2 will develop 10V across it with 8mA flowing through it:
$$ R_2 = \frac{10V}{8mA} \approx 1.2k\Omega $$
A value smaller than this may fail to switch the MOSFET on, a larger value would definitely achieve the full 10V, but would get there slower.
You aren't using PWM, and your speed requirements are relaxed, so it's not strictly necessary to have R2=1.2kΩ but 100kΩ is two orders of magnitude greater, and will cause your MOSFET's gate to discharge at a snail's pace. You can estimate how slow, very roughly, by treating the gate as a capacitor \$C_{ISS}\approx 2nF\$ (see the datasheet) discharging via R2. The time constant is:
$$ \tau = C_{ISS}R_2 = 2nF \times 100k\Omega = 200\mu s $$
That's an eternity. On the other hand, drawing 8mA from the 10V supply is going to be less efficient than drawing 100μA, so I suggest a compromise: R2 = 10kΩ, for opto transistor current of:
$$ I_C = \frac{10V}{10k\Omega} = 1mA $$
That's still well within the opto-coupler's CTR ability, while switching the MOSFET at a more reasonable speed, 10 times faster.

How does R4 affect this? Wouldn't it cause a higher current through the collector?

@Rodj Only during switching, when current is limited mostly by the opto's transistor, so you might find something like 10mA flowing via R4 for a few microseconds. R4 will not figure at all in a settled DC state, and in any case value is small and negligible compared to everything else. I would argue that you don't even need it, but that would spark a debate.
